# how can i submit form data and file using fetch in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, form-data

At first, the task was set to send data from the form. The problem was solved in the following way:

```
export let useRequest = () => {
  let request = async (url, method = "Post", body = null, headers = {}) => {
    try {
      if (body) {
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
      }

      let res = await fetch(url, { method, body, headers });
      let data = await res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
```

form:

```
 <form>
   <input name="name" class="help-input" placeholder="name" type="text" value=""/>
   <input name="email" class="help-input" placeholder="email" type="text" value=""/>
   <textarea name="message" class="help-input"placeholder="message"></textarea> 
   <input name="file" type="file" value="">
   <input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="" checked/>
   <button type="submit" onClick="props.send">send</button>
</form>
```

Form container(form wrapper):

```
export let HelpBlock = (props) => {
  let { request } = useRequest();
  let reqFromForm = async (values) => {
    let data = await request("/api/message", "POST", props.values);
    console.log(data.message)
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Form send={reqFromForm}></Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

After clicking on the button, data comes with the following structure:

```
{
    name:name,
    email:email,
    message:message,
    file:file
}
```

Comment: You need to post a form data, so, Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"

Comment: The problem is that I definitely need to write "body = JSON.stringify (body);" and because of this the line with the file becomes undefined

Comment: JSON doesn't have a "file" data type, so no … at least not unless you define how the server expects to *receive* the data.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:form-data]? You aren't using that API.

Comment: @derty14 I edited my answer, take a look ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think that you can render the body according to the content type:

```
export let useRequest = () => {
  let request = async (url, method = "Post", body = null, headers = {}, contentType="application/json" ) => {
    try {
      if (body) {
        body = renderBodyFormat(body, contentType);
        headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;  
      }

      let res = await fetch(url, { method, body, headers });
      let data = await res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
  return { request };
};

const renderBodyFormat = (data, type) => {
 const formats = {
   "application/json": ()=> JSON.stringify(body),
   "multipart/form-data": ()=> {
      const form = new FormData();
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => form.append(key, data[key]));
      return form;
   }
 } 

 return formats[type]();

}
```

EDIT: //using the hook:

```
const Component = ()=> {
 const {request} = useRequest();

 useEffect(()=> {
   const data = {
    //...other props
    file: new File(["file"], "file.txt", { type: "text/plain"});
   }

   request(url, "Post", data, {}, "multipart/form-data")
   .then(()=> {
     //...
   })
 })
}
```

Here you can find more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: after converting the property of the "file" object it is still {'0': {}}

Comment: Is file property type of File?

Comment: I meant that the value "file": {'0': {}}

Comment: You mean that renderBodyFormat return the file prop like this "file": {'0': {}}. I don't get it

Comment: When you use a file, contentType should be "multipart/form-data", in that case body is type of FormData.

Comment: Аpparently I did not describe the situation correctly. Now I will change the question.